# Remove or Fix .desktop Application's intrusive decoration

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, .desktop, desktop-icons

I want to remove or fix the white arrow in a purple background decoration that .desktop applications have by default in Focal Fossa because it's currently very intrusive.

This is my desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Diablo.exe
Comment=Diablo.exe
Exec=bash -c "wine ~/.wine/drive_c/'Program Files (x86)'/'Diablo II'/'Diablo II.exe'"
Icon=/home/armando/.wine/drive_c/windows/DIIUnin.ico
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image: A desktop file with an intrusive arrow decoration]

SOLVED. Thank you! This is how it looks after scaling the 32x32 icon to 64x64:

[image]

Comment: its a shortcut indication.. you may need to accept things for global if you want to get rid of it IMO

Comment: Sure, I am trying to ask how can I remove that shortcut indication? What do you mean "for global"?

Comment: Its just from the icon theme.. you can delete that icon.. `global` I mean all over the system you will not know the difference from regular file and symbolic linked files.. which is not good. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx9Z4.png

Comment: Sounds great! Maybe I can find a smaller, less intrusive replacement.

Comment: make local changes.. copy the icon theme folfer to local and then make your changes..

Comment: Sound like you have set your icon size to small. If you increase the icon size it will be less obtrusive. However, completely removing that symbol is not recommended as PEATAP said.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I can mark your reply as an answer since that has solved the issue. Just submit your answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @corlaez done. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you have set your icon size to small. If you increase the icon size it will be less obtrusive. However, completely removing that symbol is not recommended.